# probability of$P(A∣\lnot B)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If we have the probabilities of $P(A)$ and $P(A∣B)$, how can we calculate the probability of $P(A∣\lnot B)$?

The question statement is as follows:

A disease affects 6.5% of the population. There is however, an inheritance factor. If one’s father has the disease, the probability that the child will get the disease is 0.13. What is the probability a child will get the disease when the father does not have the disease?

How do we do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following
\begin{align*}
P(A)&=P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|\lnot B)P(\lnot B)\\
&=P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|\lnot B)(1-P(B))
\end{align*}
So that
\begin{align*}
P(A|\lnot B) &= \frac{P(A)-P(A|B)P(B)}{1-P(B)}
\end{align*}
The problem is that from $P(A)$ and $P(A|B)$ only we cannot determine $P(B)$.

Comment: We here can assume $P(B)=0.065$ as the father is a member of the population too and so has that same probability of having the disease.

Comment: I didn't look at the actual data. My answer concerns only the first question.